# how to maintain stack of an activity

Tags: android

i am new to android ,i have create a sliding drawer which contain four button,when user press option1 button an option 1.1 activity starts, in that activity their is also a button and also contain sliding drawer ,when users press button on that activity option1.1 their new activity starts of option1.1 that activity also contain sliding drawer ,now from their user open sliding drawer click on option2 than that activity starts and same process goes on as option 1

now my question is that now users presses option1 button from the activity option2.1 than its should open activity option 1.1 ......but this is not happening ...plzz help..

Comment: Have you tried using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` along with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`?

Comment: @apoorv i have create sliding drawer using fragment which contain all four button....and i have added this to all layout of an activity..

Comment: @apoorv and this fragment control all these activity..

Comment: So you move between these activities using `Intent` right?

Comment: Then please try and check if the above solution works.

Comment: @apoorv i have try this not working...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41077/discussion-between-apoorv-and-shani-goriwal)